# qDebug() input QByteArray directly and show "" I do not write

Tags: qt, resources

append my code directly:

```
QByteArray block1;
QDataStream out(&block1, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out <<int(17000);
qDebug() << block1.size();
qDebug() << block1;
qDebug() << block1.toHex();

QByteArray block2; 
QDataStream out2(&block2, QIODevice::WriteOnly); 
out2 << 'p' << 'a' << 't' << 'h';  
qDebug() << block2.size(); 
qDebug() << block2; 
qDebug() << block2.toHex();
```

[image]

My problem is there is no problem the **QByteArray** input to hex,but why input directly has **""**?

Comment: Please paste the output in the question instead of using an external image.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the situation and got (QNX 6.5.0, Qt 4.8.7 and Qt 5.5.0):

4

"

"00004268"

16

"

"00000070000000610000007400000068"

As for first array - block1[0]=0x00="\x00", block1[1]=0x00="\x00",
block1[2]=0x42="B" (ASCII), block1[3]=0x68="h"(ASCII). So you have two strings in block1 array - zero and printable "Bh".
Another array the same.

Comment: I understand your mean,just in a puzzle about separation of output string.

Comment: I don't make sure you whether understand what I mean.

Comment: You have to see for himself what you want. Print buffer as a string of characters or print buffer as an array of numbers.

Comment: Sorry,I still don't understand.Why like **qDebug() << block1;**as one syntax,will output two output string as show in the external image in the same line.

Comment: You mean differrent OS will product differrent result.I will have a try.But I think **QByteArray** should hold same bit，just treatment strategy is differrent.And output result of Windows is weird.